# voltage controlled oscillator

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, schmitt-trigger, integrator, vco

Given below is a VCO circuit. Can anyone explain how the components work (especially the resistors and capacitors) and why the resistor and capacitor values are selected so. and what are the values to calculate gain KVCO=f1−f2V1−V2.  As little as I know this is a relaxation oscillator?

(This is not a homework question)

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the voltage and resistor values of the comparator by this design tool but I haven't succeeded in doing so. (10k ohm for all three resistors)(http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/rercal.php)

Comment: Fixed your image link, but the question still may not be particularly well received - even if it is not homework, it has many of the same issues characteristic of homework problems.

Comment: If you can explain what does make sense, or why you can't get started, you're more likely to get an answer. It all looks fairly straightforward when you understand it - so what to explain?

Comment: First look at the position of C1 in relation to IC1 and recognize what category of op-amp circuit that suggests - also look at the triangle out waveform that comes directly from it.  Since the output of IC2 is a square wave you can consider Q1 a switch - think about what that makes R4 modify about the effect of the relationship of R1 vs R2 and R3, or just analyze the circuit in both states.  Lastly consider why IC2 has such "digital" behavior.

Comment: You could also look it up in Horowitz & Hill. It's Figure 4.75 on page 240 of the second edition and they describe it in fair detail. (All the components are about a quarter century older in the 2nd Ed.  but it's definitely the same circuit)